# Saving Wikipedia table data in file

Tags: python, numpy, beautifulsoup

I am trying to save a Wikipedia table to flat file. There are five tables on the page but only last one is being picked by my code. 
While trying to write data to the file, I get the following error:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import urllib.request as urr
import os
import codecs
import csv

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixteenth_Legislative_Assembly_of_Uttar_Pradesh"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia
req = urr.Request(wiki,headers=header)
page = urr.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)


lacDataSaved="#,Assembly,Name,Party,Reserved,ID,District,LS,Comments"
# find all table ,get the first
table = soup.find_all('table', class_="wikitable")[4] # Only use the first table
# iterate over it
for record in table.findAll('tr'):
    lacData=""
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        lacData=lacData+","+data.text
    lacDataSaved=lacDataSaved+"\n"+lacData[1:]

#print(lacDataSaved)

import numpy as np
np.savetxt("file_name.csv", lacDataSaved, delimiter=",")
```

I also tried using python csv library, but I was missing something there.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because one or more of your table rows seems to be a formatting row which lacks data. Your loop doesn't populate two+ elements in `lacData`, so when you ask for `lacData[1:]` Python throws an `IndexError` because the second index doesn't exist—hence the slice doesn't either.

You might be able to avoid all of this using [`pandas.read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_html.html). Not 100% sure it'll work for a table this complex, but you should give it a shot:

```
import pandas as pd
[...get the table data into a BeautifulSoup object...]
my_data = pd.read_html(str(table))
```